# Predicting from user inputs - Shiny

Tags: model, shiny

I am trying to create a web interface where i want to make predictions from a pre-built model on the inputs provided by the user.

Below is the dummy data and model

```
# creation of dummy data and model

age=round(runif(100,15,100))
bmi=round(runif(100,15,45))
cholesterol=round(runif(100,100,200))
gender=sample(c('male','female'), 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.45,0.55))
height=round(runif(100,140,200))
weight=round(runif(100,140,200))
outcome=sample(c('accepted','reject'),100,replace=T,prob=c(0.30,0.70))    
df=data.frame(age,bmi,cholesterol,gender,height,weight,outcome)
model <- glm(outcome ~.,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=df)
```

Now i'll have tried creating a shiny app referencing through multiple links and similar issues people have faced. I am beginner and still haven't been able to resolve the issue. While there is no error in running the app however, The output i.e. the probability is not printed anywhere on the web page

UI Code

```
library(shiny)
ui = fluidPage(


# this is an input object   
titlePanel("Underwriting Prediction Model"),
sidebarLayout(position = "right",
              sidebarPanel(),
              mainPanel(textOutput("Pred"))),


numericInput(inputId='age', label='Age', value = 18,min = NA, max = NA, step = NA,width = NULL),
checkboxGroupInput(inputId='gender', label='Gender', c('Male','Female'), selected = NULL, inline = FALSE,width = NULL),
numericInput(inputId='bmi', label='bmi', value = 18,min = NA, max = NA, step = NA,width = NULL),
numericInput(inputId='height', label='Height', value = 150,min = NA, max = NA, step = NA,width = NULL),
numericInput(inputId='Weight', label='Weight', value = 25, min = NA, max = NA, step = NA,width = NULL),
numericInput(inputId='cholesterol', label='Cholesterol', value = 25, min = NA, max = NA, step = NA,width = NULL),

textOutput(outputId = 'Pred')

)
```

Server

```
server = function (input,output) {
data<-reactive({
   df_final=data.frame(age=input$age,gender=input$gender,bmi=input$bmi,height=input$height,weight=input$weight,cholesterol=input$cholesterol)})

pred=reactive({predict(model,data())})

output$Pred <- renderPrint(pred())

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

When i provide the input values, i get no printed output for my predictions. I am calling the variable in render print and the main panel yet don't see any output. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your App. As @fenix_fx mentioned, you have 2 `textOutput(outputId = 'Pred')` which collide. So it would not render the output if one were created.

The `gender` input starts with a `NULL` value, so you have to wait in your reactive until a value was selected, otherwise it will throw an error, that the data.frame cannot be build because of different rows. You can do that with `req()` or `validate(need(...))`. I put a `req(input$gender)` in the  data reactive.

Another problem was that you build the `glm` model with the gender labels **male** and **female**, but your `checkboxGroupInput` gives the options **Male** and **Female**. This will give you this error and the prediction cannot be made.

> factor gender has new level Male

And last problem I think was that your input for `weight` has a capital **W**, while the data reactive waits for an input called `input$weight` with lower case **w**.

*SIDENOTE:* Your Ui seems to be arranged in a weird way. Normally you would put all inputs/outputs inside the `sidebarPanel` or `mainPanel` and not afterwards.

Resulting Code:

```
library(shiny)
ui = fluidPage(
  # this is an input object   
  titlePanel("Underwriting Prediction Model"),
  sidebarLayout(position = "left",
                sidebarPanel(
                  numericInput(inputId='age', label='Age', value = 18,min = NA, max = NA, step = NA,width = NULL),
                  checkboxGroupInput(inputId='gender', label='Gender', c('male','female'), selected = NULL, inline = FALSE,width = NULL),
                  numericInput(inputId='bmi', label='bmi', value = 18,min = NA, max = NA, step = NA,width = NULL),
                  numericInput(inputId='height', label='Height', value = 150,min = NA, max = NA, step = NA,width = NULL),
                  numericInput(inputId='weight', label='Weight', value = 25, min = NA, max = NA, step = NA,width = NULL),
                  numericInput(inputId='cholesterol', label='Cholesterol', value = 25, min = NA, max = NA, step = NA,width = NULL)
                ),
                mainPanel(textOutput("Pred")))
)

server = function (input,output) {
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$gender)
    data.frame(age=input$age,
               gender=input$gender,
               bmi=input$bmi,
               height=input$height,
               weight=input$weight,
               cholesterol=input$cholesterol)
    })

  pred <- reactive({
    predict(model,data())
  })

  output$Pred <- renderPrint(pred())
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Thanks @SeGa, the code worked. Noted on the mistakes and your comment on the UI arrangement. I am still figuring out Shiny. Will read up more. One last thing- in my output from your Code - output has a '1' before the probability. It looks like `1 0.49`

Comment: Try out with `renderText` instead of `renderPrint`

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate output 'Pred', so shiny can't do anything (in mainPanel and after all inputs in UI). Delete last and do what you need next.